# Draggable/Droppable, Sortable, or a combo?

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I've been fussing with this task for a few days now.  I cannot figure out how to get everything clicking.  I can get pieces of it working perfectly.  Either the drag and drop is perfect, or the sorting.  But I can't get the dragging, dropping, AND sorting to all work.

Here is an example of a [draggable/droppable](http://www.tyreeonline.com/dragDropTest/draggables.php).

This one is working perfectly.  Exactly how I wanted EXCEPT I cannot sort the #imgQueue at the bottom.  I don't want to be able to sort the #imgBrowser at the top.  I can drag back and forth between the browser and queue and the image clones to queue and fades in the browser.  Works great.

And here is what I'm working on for [sortables only](http://www.tyreeonline.com/dragDropTest/sortables.php).

I'm trying to accomplish a combo of the first and second examples.  Dragging and dropping from example 1 and sorting (although ONLY in the queue) from example 2.
It was suggested to me that I try to use only sortables to do all of it.  But, I'm starting to have my doubts that is possible.

Also, the sortables are very wonky in the imgQueue.  It's very hard to get them where you want them.  I'm thinking perhaps the shrinking of the images has something to do with it.  As if, perhaps, the sortable still thinks the image is 150x150 instead of 40x40???

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: are you using jquery draggables and sortables for this ?

Comment: Yep....just that and a little css.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your examples and found a weird behavior. In the second example the dragged item is not cloned, even though it should.

I did not investigate further, since I would recommend you use http://johnny.github.com/jquery-sortable/

I think you should be able to achieve what you want by mixing the first two examples.

Comment: Are the examples on that page supposed to be active?  If so, none of them work for me.  I noticed the clone (or lack of) behavior too.  Tried turning it on and off, same result.

Comment: I'm using Chrome.  Still not working for me.  Works in IE though.  Weird.  Maybe I need to clear my cache on Chrome.

Comment: In Chrome, the jQueryUI page examples work.  My samples work. http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/ That page works.  I just can't get those particular sortables to work in Chrome. Ugh!  A shame too, because that looks like it could be exactly what I need.

Comment: Chrome works for me. This is weird indeed. Maybe try force reload or private mode? Or are you on Canary?

Comment: I just had to reinstall Windows on a new drive and that page STILL doesn't work in Chrome for me!  I try to drag and it just starts selecting the elements as if it were text, etc.

Comment: are you using chrome on windows 8?

Comment: Windows 7.  Chrome version 25.0.1364.172 m.  I have no idea why it's acting this way.

Comment: I give up. Win 8 supports touch events on the desktop which might mess with the touch event support in this plugin. I'm on Win 7 with the exact same version of Chrome and it does work for me.

Comment: So weird.  I've never had a problem like this before.  Hate to imagine the hair I'd be pulling out trying to figure out why it wasn't working if I had tried to use it (thinking it was a code error or something).  Not liking that something like this just doesn't work on my browser.

Comment: Then maybe file a bug report with the author of the plugin? He might be able to help you and you might be able to solve your problem?